# VB.NET Javascript - Setting Table Row Styles when creating table

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I'm trying to use this project in VB.NET:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29436/Expandable-panel-inside-a-GridView

The problem I'm having is on the table row ID:

My Project:

```
<tr id="gridStores" style="display:none;">
```

His:

```
<tr id="gridStores_linM_30" style="display:none;">
```

I'm losing the unique ID for the row so as a result it is hiding the entire table.  So when the onClick event show / hide is being added, the unique ID is lost and it doesn't show / hide the correct row.  Everything works if I edit the code in Firebug.  This is called to add a new row to the table:

```
htmlTab.Controls.AddAt(newRowIndex, newRow)
```

Before that is called, when I called the client ID is: "linM_2"

Afterwards it is: "gridStores"

Why am I losing the name when the row is added?  Is this behavior expected for some reason?

Thank you!

My Project:
https://github.com/gbam/ExpandablePanel-VB

Working sample:
http://www.apexlogikdata.com.br/ExpandPanelGridView/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code fixed my problem:

```
    newRow.ClientIDMode = UI.ClientIDMode.Static
```

I'm not 100% sure I understand why it was needed and why VB.NET overrode my tabling naming.  If someone can edit this answer and explain more about that, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you!